# PDF file from selection in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, cell, selection

I am trying to save a selection of cells to a pdf. Everything is working except when I open the pdf it looks like html.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
  sheet2.getRange('A1:N50').activate(); *// I realise this could be the problem but not sure how to correct it*

  var url =   "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1roKWtpNPsfaQDxW82WZCfQzek77HEV4ihuC52radoXU/edit#gid=2092984379".replace("SS_ID", sheet2.getName());
  var reqFolder = '1sIxddxsPHKLKjuiArZdtrckCMxAePHR6'
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(reqFolder);
  var paymentreq = sheet1.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var creditor = sheet2.getRange("D9").getValue();
  var pdfName = 'Req ' + paymentreq + " " + creditor + " " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1","dd.MM.yyyy");

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=A4' + '&portrait=false' + 'fitw=true';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet2.getSheetId()); 
    headers: {
  Authorisation:'Bearer' + token
}

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  folder.createFile(blob);
};
```

Thank you

I have tried removing the selection section but it still only gives me html. The file when I hover over it starts with HTML: "filename.pdf"

Comment: I think that in your script, `sheet1` and `sheet2` are not declared. By this, an error occurs at `sheet2.getRange('A1:N50').activate()`. But you say `I am trying to save a selection of cells to a pdf. Everything is working except when I open the pdf it looks like html.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied the script. How about this? And, even when `sheet1` and `sheet2` are declared, `headers: { Authorisation:'Bearer' + token}` is not included in the argument of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. I'm worried that this might have also been miscopied. Please confirm it again.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike... The sheets are defined further up in the script for other elements. What is really weird is that it all works and does exactly what I want it to... the document is just in HTML. I put Adobe onto my google profile so I can open pdf's but Adobe says the file is unreadable and when I download to my computer it also does not work. Just testing a few other things now to try and see where it is going wrong. It seems to be ignoring the "pdf" part of the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From `The sheets are defined further up in the script for other elements.`, if your showing script is your actual script, please confirm my 2nd point of `And, even when sheet1 and sheet2 are declared, headers: { Authorisation:'Bearer' + token} is not included in the argument of UrlFetchApp.fetch.`. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't confirm whether you changed my 2nd point. I apologize for this.

Comment: Here is the file i get from the code output https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8H5c1hkc2dSFrJgy6GlS8EdoHOBxpzY/view?usp=share_link If I hover over the file it reads HTML: Req 1 23.01.23.pdf

Comment: When you say they are not included in the urlFetchApp.Fetch... how should this be written?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `When you say they are not included in the urlFetchApp.Fetch... how should this be written?`, I apologize for my poor English skill. Please modify ` var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet2.getSheetId());     headers: {  Authorisation:'Bearer' + token}` to `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet2.getSheetId(), {headers: {"Authorisation":'Bearer ' + token}});` and test it again.

Comment: Does exactly the same thing. :-(

Comment: I have adjusted the code slightly but can't seem to post it here. I have "Answered" myself with the current code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize. And, please delete your posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `ss`, `sheet1`, and `sheet2` are not declared.
- `headers: { Authorisation:'Bearer' + token}` is not included in `UrlFetchApp.fetch`
- `Authorisation` is not correct. It's `Authorization`.
- In your endpoint is required to be modified.
- There are 2 `gid` in your query parameter.

I think that this might be the reason for the issue with your 2nd script.

When these points are reflected, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payment Req")

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JPPgqLe5W8pQ_oGP-8oC3Ar4DRfbqrXbUwDfrxy1pM/edit#gid=2092984379" + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=A4' + '&portrait=false' + '&fitw=true' + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' + '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' + '&fzr=false' + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE' + '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); 
  var reqFolder = '1sIxddxsPHKLKjuiArZdtrckCMxAePHR6'
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(reqFolder);
  var paymentreq = sheet1.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var creditor = sheet2.getRange("D9").getValue();
  var pdfName = 'Req ' + paymentreq + " " + creditor + " " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+1","dd.MM.yyyy");

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {"Authorisation":'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});

  var theblob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + ".pdf");
  const pdfFile = folder.createFile(theblob);
  return pdfFile;
```

##### To:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Please set Spreadsheet object as ss.
var sheet1 = // Please set your sheet1.
var sheet2 = // Please set your sheet2.

var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Payment Req");
var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/\/edit/, "") + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=A4' + '&portrait=false' + '&fitw=true' + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' + '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' + '&fzr=false' + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' + '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE' + '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId();
var reqFolder = '1sIxddxsPHKLKjuiArZdtrckCMxAePHR6';
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(reqFolder);
var paymentreq = sheet1.getRange("B7").getValue();
var creditor = sheet2.getRange("D9").getValue();
var pdfName = 'Req ' + paymentreq + " " + creditor + " " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy");
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
var theblob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + ".pdf");
const pdfFile = folder.createFile(theblob);
return pdfFile;
```

Comment: @Toni Marais About `Thank you!! It works! You have made my day! ;-)`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I can't find the button?